# Winform picturebox removal to reveal text

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a poker game, player vs computer, and reveals the winner (Very simple in the rules) I decided to use Winform, and I used buttons. I went with one button to display text of the cards (Cards as images seems out of my field of range to learn, since I have two weeks to complete it) And I want to have the back of card image as a picture box, and when you hit draw cards, the picture box goes away to reveal the text card.

I asked my instructor and the way I wanted to do it he wasn't exactly sure. I have tried `=null` to get rid of it, and `(Buttonname)Image = Image.FromFile()`... I can't really find anything online to help.

Sorry for the confusion, I was in a hurry with time and probably worded it poorly. Basically I am making a five card poker game. I am using disabled buttons as the cards. I am using a picturebox titled "Back of card" to obviously have it as the back of the card. When you click "Draw cards" I want the picturebox to disappear, or hide, to show the text that is under the picturebox in the button. (the front of the card will just be text based as of now: IE: "Jack of clubs" instead of a picture of the Jack of clubs)

I don't have much code to show on what I have so far, because it is throwing me for a loop. I have placeholder text in there now, just to test it out. Here's what I have for that as of now.

`A1(buttonname).Image = ImageFromFile();`
`A1.Text = "Queen of Hearts";`

Like I said, it is just a placeholder until I finish with the rest of my code, but I want the Image, when clicked, do hide and show the "Queen of Hearts" text that's under it.

Comment: I don't see the actual question!

Comment: Please, add your code where you are having problems.

Comment: Maybe you need `PictureBox.Visible`?

Comment: So that question is *How do I hide a PictureBox?* or *How do I load an image into a PictureBox?*

Comment: I edited the post to try to clear more things up.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written it looks like you are just using a button (not a PictureBox) and using the Text and Image properties. Buttons aren't really configured to hide/show individual properties like that. On my system if I set (button).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System; it gets rid of the image, but not sure if this would be the same for all systems.

One better method would be to use 2 controls that overlap and then you can just use (picturebox).Hide(); to reveal the label/textbox or another picturebox underneath.

For each 'card' create a placeholder using a Panel control that you set to your desired card size. While your at it, set BorderStyle to something other than None as well.
Create a Label control inside of the Panel, set Dock to Fill, TextAlign to MiddleCenter, and change the Text property to a card name ('Queen Of Spades').
Now create a PictureBox control inside the Panel as well and also set it's Dock to Fill, Image to your card's background image and SizeMode to StretchImage or Zoom.
Now you will have a card background that perfectly covers a hidden card which you can reveal by using (Panel).Hide();

Of course you could replace the Label with another PictureBox to show a picture of a card instead.
If you want to use the Label, on your numpad try using ALT-3 for ♥, ALT-4 ♦, ALT-5 ♣ and ALT-6 ♠ for some card symbols ;)